# Why am I getting an error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Getting an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Before reloading the page it's work fine. But when I'm reloading the page getting an error. I want to get object values from array.

[image]

```
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchData} from '../../actions/fetchData';

class Menu extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    const {data, isFetching} = this.props.data;

    if (isFetching) {
      return (
        <View>
          <ActivityIndicator size={'large'} />
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}>
          <Text>
            {data.categories.map(nm => nm.name)}
            {/* {console.log("data",data.categories.map(nm => nm.name))} */}
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    data: state.data,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    ...bindActionCreators({fetchData}, dispatch),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Menu);
```

Comment: `data.categories` is undefined, check why that's happening or use `data.categories && data.categories.map()`

Comment: Hi, when I console.log(data.categories), it's showing correct, but when I'm adding map, it's crushing and map undefined. But, data.categories && data.categories.map() is working fine.

Comment: Why you init data in state again with data which are in redux store? Just use this.props.data.map() and don't forget to initialize state with empty array in reducer.

Comment: I updated code, can you pls check it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a `react-native` developer, but have working small experience on `react`. Here what I can understand as given below:

```
this.state = {
  data: this.props.data,
};
```

In above code in `constructor`, first initialize with `state.data`, when class instance is called and it will be `undefined`. Because when first class is called, `this.props.data` is `undefined`.

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.fetchData();
}
```

After `constructor`'s task complete, above code will be executed and it's data is shown in `console.log`. But returned data is never assign to any variable. That means, after fetching data, `this.state.data` still is `undefined`.

so when comes to executing `<Text>{this.state.data.data.categories.map(nm => nm.name)}</Text>` , `this.state.data` will be undefined`. To solve this problem, you can try following code:

```
class Menu extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.data.data.categories.map(nm => nm.name)}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And one last thing, I strongly recommend that, you learn react development life-cycle. Thanks

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but still problem with map and when I'm using this data.categories && data.categories.map() the problems gone dunno why

Comment: I think you might have problem with `mapStateToProps` or `this.props.data.data.categories`.

Comment: when I console.log(this.props.data.data.categories) it's showing correct, but when I'm going deeper сonsole.log(this.props.data.data.categories.map()), become an error

Answer (score 0):

I've got this problem before and i solved it for mapping through images array  , because fetching data is asynchronous it seems like data is not available at beginning of rendering and causes of err  when mapping , You should handle your app and prevent rendering before data is set into the state  , so implement a checker to see data is completely available in state and then let render , it's the only solution and nothing else

Comment: Still problem with map.

Comment: send me your last changes to help better

Comment: Answer eddited.